# Error in Fetching Product from ID in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce

String Query **checkuser** is not concatenating product id to get seleted item,
may be its a parsing issue.

the result shows the query string as a whole but not item.

Checkout button code:

```
public partial class WebSite1_checkout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   List<item> li = new List<item>();
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      for(int i=1; i<=Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]) ;i++)
       {
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CM_Connection"].ConnectionString);
           conn.Open();
           item items = new item();
           items.Id = Session["id" + i].ToString();
          string checkuser = "select prod_name from productt where prod_id='" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]) + "'";


           SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            //string temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
           items.Name = checkuser;

           li.Add(items);
       }
       GridView1.DataSource = li;
       GridView1.DataBind();

   }
```

Comment: One thing to try is what is the value of items.Id when debugging?

Comment: it shows 0 only and display whole string of query instead of fetched items

Comment: Ok i understand i think you need to execute the sql command. At the the moment i cannot see where you are executing the command so your list of items is just holding a string . This link could be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah you are right, uploading working code

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong in the code. Are you sure Session["id"] is not null ?

Comment: yes session is not null and perfectly working but doesn't passing value to query

Comment: "the result shows the query string as a whole but not item." By Result do you mean items.Name ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; i<=Convert.ToInt32(Session["count"]) ;i++)
       {
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CM_Connection"].ConnectionString);
           conn.Open();
           item items = new item();
           items.Id = Session["id" + i].ToString();
           string checkuser = "select prod_name from productt where prod_id=" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["id" + i]) ;
           SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
           string temp= (com.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
           items.Name = temp;






           li.Add(items);

       }
```

> this is the working code....thanks to all